# How do I set my clan tag in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've tried looking for official faqs, forums, etc.  I know how to create/join a clan but I can't find any proper instructions to get my battletag to display something like:

```
<clan_name> battletag
```

I'm sorry if the answer to this is incredibly obvious but I've tried to change both in game and on Battlenet's website and I cannot figure out how to do this for the life of me despite seeing various people with their own clan tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information I have gathered and summarized from this [thread](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/sc2/topic/8197591343) it goes like this:

> From the opening screen of the game, bottom right hand corner, down by
>   where your friends list is, there's a second button for Groups/Clans.
>   You can create one from there.

This might means you have made a group not a clan. Do the following to make it a clan

> Login, main screen, groups chat, create, on the dropdown, click "clan" instead of leaving it on "group"